# How to Refresh or re render DIV in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have an attachment button that works fine. Now I want to cancel button which cancels the uploaded file. For this, I need to re-render the div by clicking the cancel button. How ?.IS there is better solution.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="File Upload LWC" icon-name="custom:custom14">
       
        <div class="slds-m-left_xx-large"> /* ----> this DIV   */
            <label style="display: inline-block;position: relative;height: 50px;width: 150px;" for="inputFile">
                <div style="position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;bottom: 0;
                            width: 100%;display: flex;border-radius: 10px;
                            align-items: center;justify-content: center;background: rgb(214, 211, 211);
                            border: 3px dotted #ffffff;">
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:attach" alternative-text="attach!" title="attach" size="xx-small" ></lightning-icon>        Attachment
        </div>        
        <lightning-input type="file"   style="position: absolute;left: 0;opacity: 0;top: 0;bottom: 0;width: 100%;"
        accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv, .png, .doc, .docx, .pdf"
        label="Attachment tt" onchange={openfileUpload}></lightning-input>
      </label>
     </div>
     
  
        {filename}
      
   </lightning-card> 
    
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do this by using conditional rendering. Encapsulate your div with

```
<template if:true={isUploaderVisible}></template>
```

Make isUploaderVisible false when you press the cancel button. Show a spinner with setTimeout then set isUploaderVisible to true again. That way this uploader will be removed from the DOM and added again.

Comment: cancelUploadFile(){
    this.isUploaderVisible = false;

    setTimeout(function(){
        
        this.isUploaderVisible = true;
       
    }, 1000);
    console.log('called out side' );
}

Comment: after the value make false then  in the set timeout   function I want to make values true but it's not working